# Exchange Migration Batch In-Progress

Tags: windows, powershell, exchange

I am working on migrating users from exchange 2013 to exchange 2019 and ran into an issue when the disk was not large enough for the migration, causing the job to error out and one user to stop migration in progress. Now whenever I try to migrate that user it immediately jumps to the 8 gigabytes already synchronized and stalls due to the destination.

I'm looking for a way to delete the partially migrated data or resolve the issue of the batch job completing with 0 out of 0 to a different database.

Alternatively I've tried migrating the user to a different database and the batch job completes with 0 out of 0 mailboxes moved. I've tried removing and recreating batch jobs as well as restarting servers with no success.

We have also started seeing a delay in outbound email of around 2-3 minutes however this did not start occurring until today whereas the migration batch issues were seen in the previous two weeks.

Comment: I will suggest using New-MoveRequest instead to see if you can move the mailboxes, while note that it will also depend on the available resources (migration has lower priority than mail flow and client connectivity).

Comment: @Kael That seems to be making progress on the user I was having trouble with, will update once the job is completed (shouldn't take too long as they're only an 8gb mailbox)

Comment: @Kael the move request completed without issue, thank you for the help. It also gave me some more information regarding the 2-3 minute delay in outbound emails that I was seeing and will hopefully have that resolved with another move request.